# Change background color, on portfolio option

Tags: wordpress, css, background-color

Firstly, the site is called, anarrayofstars.com/temp/.

So I am trying to change the background colour on Bar Isabel and the other portfolio items. I want them all to be different colours on idle state and hover state.

I have tried everything to change the background colour for just the one module
- I targeted just module i.e #module-1280, no luck.
- I targeted the all the modules, and it didn't change.
- So nowI'm stuck

Some of the code samples I tried are:

```
#module-1280{
  background-color: #FF0000;
} 

#module-1280:hover{
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

I cannot seem to tell you why this isn't working. Maybe it has something to do with the background-color, I also tried to apply !important, but it still didn't work. I know its not a lot of information to go on but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the a-tag that got the background-attribute.. Try this:

```
#module-1280 a{
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

It should work.